# open div on click is not centered on scroll

Tags: html, css

I did try using position:fixed; (I saw another topic with similar problem)

[Here is the page I am working on](http://www.healncure.com/ubook-test-2/)

**The Problem**: click on the "*Click to view acute conditions" which is under Same Day Appointments. This opens up a div that is position:fixed 50% top & left of the page but not when scrolled down.

[Here is a Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5cXv/2/) (only the preview frame: http://jsfiddle.net/u5cXv/2/embedded/result/)

**The Code**: Below is the parent div

```
#ubookwhite_content {
    Background-color:#fff;
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    outline:solid 10px #cccccc;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 25px;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The Javascript is a simple open close function. Can you please help me understand why this doesn't position when scrolled down.

Comment: On your live page, `position:fixed` gets overwritten with `position:absolute` on line 863.

Comment: Ok so inspect element on the page (not the fiddle) you provided has the `position: absolute`, but your fiddle has `position: fixed`. I think if you change it to fixed it will work.

Comment: I think it's the .show() that does that...

Comment: @StevoPerisic - If you widen out the frame in jsfiddle, it has the same problem (offset to the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the styles for that element in two places. Here is the other one:

```
#ubookwhite_content {
  Background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 5px #cccccc;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 25px;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

That second is after the first and uses position:absolute

Comment: The fiddle shows the same problem when the frame is widened out, and using only one with `position: fixed` does not offset it correctly. This is only an observation, not an answer. Also, `background-color` should be lowercase.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that it was written twice, I am a fool for not ctrl-f finding it. @Jared Farrish thanks, I'll change that.

Answer (score 1):

The width of your `#ubookwhite_content` is `800px`, but once the padding is added in, the actual element width is `850px`. This is setting your element off by `50px` when you use `margin-left: 400px`.

You can either make the `width: 750px` or make the offset `margin-left: 425px`. Either way takes into account the additional width of the `padding: 25px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5cXv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your website doesn't match what you copy and pasted onto the website. The position on the website isn't fixed: it's absolute, which is completely different. If your code says fixed, you may need to re-upload to your server.

This is apparently located on index: line 860.

I would also recommend using google's "inspect" command in order to investigate later issues.

Comment: The code was written twice, one with position:absolute and one with position:fixed. I should have did a ctrl-find on my source code. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margins or playing around withit. Keep the `position: absolute`

`margin-top: -150px;`